# aiogram ошибка Can't parse inline keyboard button: text buttons are unallowed in the inline keyboard

Tags: python, aiogram

вот пример кода:

```
from aiogram.types import InlineKeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup

markup_games = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
markup_games.add(InlineKeyboardButton(
    'Ігрові Двигуни'))
markup_games.add(InlineKeyboardButton(
    '.'))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Инлайн кнопки должны иметь хотя бы одно опциональное поле: `callback_data`, `url`, `switch_inline_query` и т.д.
https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inlinekeyboardbutton  *(You **must** use exactly one of the optional fields.)*

Если нужны текстовые кнопки - `ReplyKeyboardMarkup`.